# Compiling with static GL libraries in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I am trying to statically link GL, GLEW, and GLFW in my CMake-based program.

Here is my current, working, non-static CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(GLApp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
file(GLOB SRC_LIST "src/*")
file(COPY "glsl" "tex" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(GLApp GL GLEW glfw)
```

I tried adding the following line (below the `file COPY` line) to make the libraries statically linked:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

But I receive the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw
```

Comment: Missing to specify additional linker directories?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What directory should I specify? Do I need to have a specific static build of the libraries downloaded, or do I just need to point CMake to the right directory on my system?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -L<path to search for libraries>")`

Comment: I think there's a CMake specific command like `link_directories` or such as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, I believe you've set me on the right path. Now I just need to find out where the `.a` files are on my system.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindOpenGL.html